# Installed R package different from a used R package to build another package

Tags: r, installation

I am attempting to write a R package. As I run

`devtools::check()`, one of the warnings messages is

`Found the following significant warnings:
  Warning: Installed Rcpp (0.12.12) different from Rcpp used to build dplyr (0.12.10).`

I then

`remove.packages("Rcpp")`

and

`install.packages("Rcpp", repo = "https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.4/Rcpp_0.12.10.tgz")`

It gives me
`Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.4/Rcpp_0.12.10.tgz/src/contrib/PACKAGES.rds': HTTP status was '404 Not Found'`

What would be the best solution to this? Thank you very much!!

Comment: It's more or less line noise generated by `dplyr` which you can ignore.  It is not an `rcpp` issue so I will remove the `rcpp` tag as well.

Answer (score 2):

You should not worry too much about this error if you are still drafting this package (*i.e.* there's still some time to go before you actually use it), as it's possible there will be another change of version of these two packages. Obviously if you encounter any strange errors, or there are features from the most recent versions of either, you should fix it.

It's inadvisable to downgrade a package (*i.e.* change `Rcpp` in your case); instead, you should upgrade both `dplyr` and `Rcpp` to a concurrent version. This can be best achieved by using the CRAN repository. In a fresh session,

```
remove.packages(c("dplyr", "Rcpp"))
## Restart
install.packages("dplyr")  # Rcpp is a dependency
```

Note: to install a particular version, use `devtools::install_version`:

```
devtools::install_version("Rcpp", version = "0.12.10")
```

The error you got was you directed `install.packages` to look at the package *file* as if it were a package *repository*. This resulted in an HTTP 404 error, as there was no `PACKAGES.rds` file relative to the phantom repository.

To install a package file directly, set `repos=NULL` in `install.packages`.